# Auto populate second EditText based on first EditText input

Tags: java, android, auto-populate

I'm brainstorming the next phase of my project, and I'm not certain which path to take. My idea is to have 2 EditText fields, one beneath the other. When the user types a unique ID into the first field, the second field will populate automatically with corresponding text. For example, entering "X5432" in box 1 will put "1957 Thunderbird" in box 2. I estimate having about 500 value pairs to work from, so I assume a SQLite structure would be better than just using arrays. Any suggestions would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Have you try ajax scripting?.

Comment: I've never worked with ajax, but if it'll do what I need it to I'll certainly give it a shot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should use `TextWatcher`.

1. Just get value from edittext1
2. Find appropriate text for edittext2
3. Set text to second edittext.

   ```
   edittext.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

       @Override
       public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
           // do some stuff

       }

       @Override
       public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
               int after) {
           // do some stuff

       }

       @Override
       public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
           // do some stuff

       }
   });
   ```

Comment: I think this sounds like the best bet. Thanks